# AppFog available RAM for MySQL service

Tags: appfog

Does anyone know how much RAM does a MySQL instance have in the AppFog platform.

(yes I have read https://www.appfog.com/pricing/ and I am already a paying customer, but their support cannot answer me and I feel like in Catch 22) - from their pricing I know that the available storage is 200 MB for the 20$ plan but ... there is no way to check how much RAM.

When I type : af info

```
Target:   https://api.appfog.com (v0.999)
Client:   v0.3.18.12

User:     support@moreforecast.com
Usage:    Memory   (320.0M of 2.0G total)
          Services (2 of 8 total)
          Apps     (2 of 9999 total)
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no clue. Hint: if their support doesn't know, it's unlikely SO will. My guess: mysql servers host many databases and they scale them "on demand". Once a server is saturated, a new one will be added ...it doesn't even have to be the same specs. In other words, the memory may vary. ...but why would you need a lot of RAM anyway?

Comment: It seems that I'm not the only one that noticed the lack of information regarding their MySQL documentation. Probably if I need more robust MySQL service I will use one from the partner Add-Ons